# How do I make the numbering label bigger size?

Tags: numbering, labels

Currently, I am using this code.
I used scriptsize command so that some fractions does not overfull the page..

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{align}
   \nonumber &E_{PP}^* = (S_b^*, I_b^*, S_h^*, I_a^*, R_h^*) = \Big(\frac{H_b(\mu_b + \delta_b) + \Lambda_b}{\mu_b + \beta_b}, \frac{\beta_b\Lambda_b - H_b\mu_b(\mu_b + \delta_b)}{(\mu_b + \delta_b)(\mu_b + \beta_b)},\\ \nonumber &\frac{\Lambda_h[\beta_b\Lambda_b-H_b\mu_b(\delta_b+\mu_b)+H_{bh}(\beta_b+\mu_b)(\delta_b+\mu_b)]}{\mu_b(\delta_b+\mu_b)[\beta_{bh}(cq-1)H_b-H_b\mu_h+H_{bh}\mu_h]+\beta_b\big\lbrack\beta_{bh}(\Lambda_b-cq\Lambda_b)+\mu_h[H_{bh}(\delta_b+\mu_b)+\Lambda_b]\big\rbrack},\\\nonumber
     &-\frac{\beta_{bh}(cq-1)\Lambda_h[\beta_b\Lambda_b-H_b\mu_b(\delta_b+\mu_b)]}{(\gamma_a+d+\mu_h)\Big\lbrack\mu_b(\delta_b+\mu_b)[\beta_{bh}(cq-1)H_b-H_b\mu_h+H_{bh}\mu_h]+\beta_b\big\lbrack\beta_{bh}(\Lambda_b-cq\Lambda_b)+\mu_h[H_{bh}(\delta_b+\mu_b)+\Lambda_b]\big\rbrack\Big\rbrack},\\\nonumber
     &-\frac{\beta_{bh}\gamma_a(cq-1)\Lambda_h[\beta_b\Lambda_b-H_b\mu_b(\delta_b+\mu_b)]}{\mu_h(\gamma_a+d+\mu_h)\Big\lbrack\mu_b(\delta_b+\mu_b)[\beta_{bh}(cq-1)H_b-H_b\mu_h+H_{bh}\mu_h]+\beta_b\big\lbrack\beta_{bh}(\Lambda_b-cq\Lambda_b)+\mu_h[H_{bh}(\delta_b+\mu_b)+\Lambda_b]\big\rbrack\Big\rbrack}\Big).\\\label{Eqn: PPEE}
\end{align}
\end{scriptsize}
```

and the output is this: 
[image]

I want to make number labeling (67) to be in regular font or not in scriptsize font. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I think that change font size is not so good as giving notation for some long expression and reducing the size of equation factors. It is almost impossible to fit such long line into the document body.

Comment: So there's no way to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whether or not you want to use equation numbers I suggest it would be easier for the reader if you write these equations like this:

[image]

You may not want to separate it out this much but you *definitely should* give a name to the common part of the denominator of these equations as this makes it much easier to understand. (It's not unlikely that this `X`, or whatever you want to call it, is also "important" given that it appears in so many places.) As stated already in the comments, using `scriptsize` should be avoided if at all possible.

The full code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
   Now, $E_{PP}^*= (S_b^*, I_b^*, S_h^*, I_a^*, R_h^*)$, where
   \begin{align}
  S_b^* &= \frac{H_b(\mu_b + \delta_b) + \Lambda_b}{\mu_b + \beta_b},\\
  I_b^* &=\frac{\beta_b\Lambda_b - H_b\mu_b(\mu_b + \delta_b)}{(\mu_b + \delta_b)(\mu_b + \beta_b)},\\
  S_h^* &=\frac{\Lambda_h[\beta_b\Lambda_b-H_b\mu_b(\delta_b+\mu_b)+H_{bh}(\beta_b+\mu_b)(\delta_b+\mu_b)]}{X},\\
  I_a^* &=-\frac{\beta_{bh}(cq-1)\Lambda_h[\beta_b\Lambda_b-H_b\mu_b(\delta_b+\mu_b)]}{(\gamma_a+d+\mu_h)X},\\
  R_h^*  &=-\frac{\beta_{bh}\gamma_a(cq-1)\Lambda_h[\beta_b\Lambda_b-H_b\mu_b(\delta_b+\mu_b)]}{\mu_h(\gamma_a+d+\mu_h)X},\\
   \intertext{and}
   X&=\mu_b(\delta_b+\mu_b)[\beta_{bh}(cq-1)H_b-H_b\mu_h+H_{bh}\mu_h]+\\\nonumber
  & \quad+\beta_b\big\lbrack\beta_{bh}(\Lambda_b-cq\Lambda_b)+\mu_h[H_{bh}(\delta_b+\mu_b)+\Lambda_b]\big\rbrack

  \end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice. Just typo: there are mismatching brackets on `X`.

Comment: What about put `X` on another block with a gathered  single number? `\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
X&=\mu_b(\delta_b+\mu_b)[\beta_{bh}(cq-1)H_b-H_b\mu_h+H_{bh}\mu_h]+\\
& \quad+\beta_b\big\lbrack\beta_{bh}(\Lambda_b-cq\Lambda_b)+\mu_h[H_{bh}(\delta_b+\mu_b)+\Lambda_b]\big\rbrack
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}`

Comment: @Sigur Oops, I must have accidentally changed the `align*` to `align` as my original post did not have line numbers (I number as few things as possible in my own work...). I've fixed the numbers up for `X`.

Comment: I would split and move `X` to another block since the whole block including `and` could be long and produce some page breaks.

Comment: @Sigur I agree that are other possible improvements, some of which will depend on where these equations fit inside a large document. The main point of my post is that the `X` should be named and defined separately. The other details such as which equations are numbered and how they grouped I think is best left up to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this layout, based on `alignedat` and using `mathtools`, `nccmath` (for the medium-sized fractions) and `geometry` (to have more decent horizontal margins, if you don't use marginal notes):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{equation}\label{Eqn: PPEE}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
 &\mathrlap{ E_{PP}^* = (S_b^*, I_b^*, S_h^*, I_a^*, R_h^*) = \biggl(\mfrac{H_b(\mu_b + \delta_b) + \Lambda_b}{\mu_b + \beta_b}, \mfrac{\beta_b\Lambda_b - H_b\mu_b(\mu_b + \delta_b)}{(\mu_b + \delta_b)(\mu_b + \beta_b)}}, & &\\%
  & & \mfrac{\Lambda_h[\beta_b\Lambda_b-H_b\mu_b(\delta_b+\mu_b)+H_{bh}(\beta_b+\mu_b)(\delta_b+\mu_b)]}%
   {\begin{rcases}\splitfrac{\rule{0pt}{2ex}\,\mu_b(\delta_b+\mu_b)\bigl[\beta_{bh}(cq-1)H_b-H_b\mu_h+H_{bh}\mu_h\bigr]}{+\beta_b\bigl[\beta_{bh}(\Lambda_b-cq\Lambda_b)%
   + \mu_h \bigl(H_{bh}(\delta_b+\mu_b)+\Lambda_b\bigr)\bigr]}\end{rcases}{\textstyle \rlap D}} & ,\\[0.5ex] %
    & & -\mfrac{\beta_{bh}(cq-1)\Lambda_h\bigl[\beta_b\Lambda_b-H_b\mu_b(\delta_b+\mu_b)\bigr]} %
     {(\gamma_a+d+\mu_h)D},%
     -\mfrac{\beta_{bh}\gamma_a(cq-1)\Lambda_h\bigl[\beta_b\Lambda_b-H_b\mu_b(\delta_b+\mu_b)\bigr]}%
     {\mu_h(\gamma_a+d+\mu_h)D}\biggr) & .
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: based on <code>alignedat</code>]